# Receiving ImportError attempting to import custom service file to service server node

Tags: python, ros, ubuntu-22.04, ros2

I'm attempting to build a ROS2 network in which a service server node reads data from a sensor.py script and makes it available to a custom service. When I attempt to import my .srv file from the package folder I'm in, I receive an error

```
bin/python3 /home/name/ros2_ws/src/dof_filter_service_pkg/dof_filter_service_pkg/service_server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/ros2_ws/src/dof_filter_service_pkg/dof_filter_service_pkg/service_server.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dof_filter_service_pkg import dof_filter
ImportError: cannot import name 'dof_filter' from 'dof_filter_service_pkg' (/home/name/ros2_ws/install/dof_filter_service_pkg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dof_filter_service_pkg/__init__.py)
```

Here's the setup to my service_server.py file:

```
import rclpy
import numpy as np
import socket
import time

from rclpy.node import Node
from dof_filter_service_pkg import dof_filter

class ServiceServer(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('service_server')
        self.service = self.create_service(dof_filter, 'service_server_topic',self.service_callback)
```

Here's my dof_filter.srv file inside an srv folder

```
# service_client sends an empty request
# number_of_samples is a fixed amount handled in service_server

---

# Response message:

float32 filtered_data
```

My package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>dof_filter_service_pkg</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>3-DOF ROS2 Package</description>
  <maintainer email="name@todo.todo">name</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <build_depend>rclpy</depend>
  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>

  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_generators</exec_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

I don't receive any errors doing colcon build, only when attempting to run service_server.py. All of these files are inside my src > dof_filter_service_pkg > dof_filter_service_pkg folder. Using Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble, and Python 3.10. Thank you!

`

I've tried colcon build, taking dof_filter.srv outside the folder and into the package directory, and changing `from dof_filter_service_pkg import dof_filter` to `from dof_filter_service_pkg.srv import dof_filter`

Comment: Did you confirm the `srv` file is actually being built? You may need to provide your build file.

Comment: I used colcon build in my src folder, which then tells me 1 package is successfully built, my dof_filter_service_pkg. Is my .srv file being built in this case? How can I actually check?

Comment: You can look to see if the srv is in your build/install folder. All that message means is that the package built. Built packages don’t have to include everything in the package source, only what you have specified in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: My build/install folders do not have my .srv file in them, only __init__.py and service_server_node. How do I build my .srv file? Do I have to make changes to my package.xml or setup.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment it seems like you're including the `srv` file in your `ament_python` package. Typically it is recommended that you create a package specifically for your message and service file definitions. You can do this by creating a new `ament_cmake` package via: `ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake tutorial_interfaces`. Next you should make your srv file directory with `mkdir srv` and put your service definition there. Then edit your `CMakeLists.txt` to include the build step for your service:

```
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "srv/YourService.srv"
)
```

And finally make sure the default generators are included in your `package.xml`

```
<build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>

<exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>

<member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
```

Then you can build it like any other colcon package.